# 'How do you want to open' 8.1 dialog and icons

Tags: windows-8.1, default-programs

Does anyone know, where Win 8.1 gets the icons, used in the dialog, from?

[image]

In my case an app icon is corrupted (instead of mine, another app icon is used for my app), and I want to debug the issue. But for that I have to know, where is a source of the icons.

I've already inspected my .exe file resources, there is no other icons there but mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that when an app is registering itself as matching some user's model, it should set the logo and background color. See AppUserModelId (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.